# How to use Kotlin to inspect all calls of a particular function?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

In our codebase we have a third-party library method that behaves in an unexpected manner when you pass `null` to it. To help prevent misuse of the method, I would like to write a test that walks through the codebase, finds all calls to the method, and makes sure the type of the single parameter passed in is not nullable.

Is this possible using Kotlin reflection? Is this possible in Kotlin at all? I can get to the point where I list out all the functions in the codebase, but am stumped on how to continue!

Comment: It might be easier write your own proxy method, and then prohibit *any* call to the third party method except via the proxy. If practical, isolate the entire third party library behind your own API.

Comment: @TechInquisitor This is a large, established codebase, so I'm trying to avoid solutions that involve a refactor. Thank you for the suggestion!